# The same data on all pages of pager

Tags: drupal, pagination, twig, drupal-8

I wrote a pagination in my custom module, but the pager displays the same data on all its pages. My query has **4 elements**. I want to display **2 elements per page**. I use `range(0,4)` and it shows me all 4 elements on every page, I tried lots of combinations of `range()`. How can I display 2 elements per page? Please help :) My code:

```php
   public function news() {
    $query = $this->entityTypeManager
    ->getListBuilder('node')
    ->getStorage()
    ->getQuery();
    $query->condition('type', 'aktualnosc');
    $query->condition('status', 1);
    $result = $query->range(0, 4)->execute();
    $nodes = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('node')->loadMultiple($result);

    pager_default_initialize(count($result), 2);

    $render = [];
    $render[] = [
      '#theme' => 'news',
      '#results' => $nodes,
      '#type' => 'remote'
    ];

    $render[] = [
      '#type' => 'pager',
      '#quantity' => 2
    ];

    return $render;
  }
```

Comment: Try posting on https://drupal.stackexchange.com/ if you don't get an answer here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a tiny mistake, you always `::range()` from 0 to 4 elements. Instead, you should use the `::pager()` method instead.

Here is the same function as yours but using the `pager` instead of `range`.

```
public function news() {
    $query = $this->entityTypeManager
        ->getListBuilder('node')
        ->getStorage()
        ->getQuery();

    $query->condition('type', 'aktualnosc');
    $query->condition('status', 1);

    // Get all the aktualnosc nodes to initialize our pager.
    $nids = $query->execute();
    pager_default_initialize(count($nids), 2);

    $query->pager($limit);

    // Fetch nodes based on our pager.
    $nids = $query->execute();
    $nodes = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('node')->loadMultiple($nids);

    $render = [];
    $render[] = [
      '#theme' => 'news',
      '#results' => $nodes,
      '#type' => 'remote'
    ];

    $render[] = [
      '#type' => 'pager',
      '#quantity' => 2
    ];

    return $render;
}
```